# SED with variable that migth contain " / "

Tags: bash, sed

I have this code:

```
echo $content | grep -o '<a href="[a-z]\+[^>"]*' | sed -ne 's/^<a href="\(.*\)/\1/p' | sed -ne 's~/^http[s]*:\/\/*\(.*\)/\1/p' | sed -ne "s;/\([^/]*\)\/\(.*\)/$1:::$2:::\1:::\2/;p"
```

If you look at the last sed command, you can see the variable $2.

And the $2 variable might contain a forward-slash "/", and this will obviously cause problems.

How can I avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, change the sed delimiters..

```
sed -ne "s~\([^/]*\)\/\(.*\)~$1:::$2:::\1:::\2~p"
```

Your last two sed commands should be,

```
sed -ne 's~^http[s]*:\/\/*\(.*\)~\1~p' | sed -ne "s;\([^/]*\)\/\(.*\);$1:::$2:::\1:::\2;p"
```

Comment: or `sed -ne "s;\([^/]*\)\/\(.*\);$1:::$2:::\1:::\2;p"`

Comment: Tested and not working, I get this error: unterminated `s' command

Comment: post the full traceback on your question

Comment: Posted the full code I use if that is what you mean with  full traceback

Comment: @Jozo pls have a check on second and third sed commands.. You need to replace sed delimiter `/` with `;`